# Using "transform: translate" with JS only works once

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, listener, transform

I'm tyring to move a div every time I click a button. It should always move the same distance. I'm doing this with JavaScript, but I can't seem to get it working after the first click.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="slide"></div>
  <div class="slide"></div>
  <div class="slide"></div>
</div>
<button id="move">Click to move the square</button>
```

CSS

```
.slide {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("move").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("container").style.transform = "translateX(30px)"
})
```

I've tried calling the function from outside the event listener, like this:

```
document.getElementById("move").addEventListener("click", clickNext);
function clickNext() {
  document.getElementById("container").style.transform = "translateX(30px)"
}
```

I've also tried to handle the click event through HTML with the "onclick" attribute:

HTML

```
<button id="move" onclick="clickNext()">Click to move the square</button>
```

JS

```
function clickNext() {
  document.getElementById("container").style.transform = "translateX(-100px)"
}
```

In every one of these code bits the button works as intendedb but only once. After that, the button stops working.

Any help on why that's happening would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there is no change in the `style` property being assigned on the second occurrence of the click hence there is no `animation`

Try this:

```js
var amount = 30;
var initial = 0;
document.getElementById("move").addEventListener("click", function() {
  initial += amount;
  document.getElementById("container").style.transform = "translateX(" + initial + "px)"
})
```

```css
.slide {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="slide"></div>
  <div class="slide"></div>
  <div class="slide"></div>
</div>
<button id="move">Click to move the square</button>
```